# Zig-Zag sequence[Dynamic Programming] bugs

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, dynamic-programming

I currently learning DP and I was studying via the topsider tutorial, and was trying to solve the problem [ZigZag sequence](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=1259&rd=4493) and understand and know that the solution would be very similar to computing the length go longest increasing subsequence. I programmed a simple c++ DP solution as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int numbers[] =         
{ 374, 40, 854, 203, 203, 156, 362, 279, 812, 955, 
600, 947, 978, 46, 100, 953, 670, 862, 568, 188, 
67, 669, 810, 704, 52, 861, 49, 640, 370, 908, 
477, 245, 413, 109, 659, 401, 483, 308, 609, 120, 
249, 22, 176, 279, 23, 22, 617, 462, 459, 244 };
    vector<int> length(n, 1);
    for(int i = 1;i < n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = (i - 1);j >= 0;j--)
        {
            if(length[j] + 1 > length[i])
            {
                if(length[j] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if(numbers[i] - numbers[j] < 0)
                    {
                        length[i] = length[j] + 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(numbers[i] - numbers[j] > 0)
                    {
                        length[i] = length[j] + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", *(max_element(length.begin(), length.end())));
}
```

But the problem is that the code works fine for all other cases, except this one:

```
{ 374, 40, 854, 203, 203, 156, 362, 279, 812, 955, 
600, 947, 978, 46, 100, 953, 670, 862, 568, 188, 
67, 669, 810, 704, 52, 861, 49, 640, 370, 908, 
477, 245, 413, 109, 659, 401, 483, 308, 609, 120, 
249, 22, 176, 279, 23, 22, 617, 462, 459, 244 }
```

My code prints the answer `35` while topsider believes its `36`. I know Im making some kind of silly mistake in the program, but have been trying to find it since quite some time now, can someone else help me figure out the bug ?

Comment: The biggest bug in your program is that it has no comments. This is fine for a programming competition, but not when you submit it to a forum like this one for help and advice.

Comment: @TonyK Ya, I know, that's one of my biggest weaknesses, In really sorry that I'm so competition minded, but I just sometimes feel that adding comments to code break ones workflow and sometimes end up messing code... Moreover, I'm preparing for INOI these days, hence my focus is completely on algorirhms, and not beauty of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the first difference can be either positive or negative, but your code only supports one of these cases.

Maybe you should run this code twice, once with positive first, then the second time with negative first.